# Calculate induced voltage in a wire due to mains wiring

Tags: electromagnetism, induction, mutual-inductance

I wish to calculate voltage induced in a short piece of wire of known length, due to mains household wiring carrying some current say 5 amps. My application is biomedical sensor wire and I can not use a shielded wire. my sensor wire is connected to a small battery operated circuit. so can       capacitive coupling can be neglected? Does this mean that the coupling is mainly inductive ?  How will the induced interference voltage vary with distance and orientation of my biomedical sensor wire from the mains wiring?

Comment: Maxwell's law...curl E = -dB/dt. Partial differentials of course (not very easy to use in comments)

Comment: Sorry for the (slight) digression but are you sure the household electricity wire is the only source of EMI you should worry about since you do not use a shielded cable ? What about RF interference (mobile phones, wifi, TV, ...) ?

Comment: Yes. Coupling can be assumed to be mostly inductive. I require an (aproximate) formula to calculate induced emf in my sensor wire of known length and known average mains current. We also assume that both wires are parallel to each other at a known distance.

Comment: @maximGi, bandwidth of my preamp is 100Hz and has a rc filter at input. So I think mains is the mostly troublesome part. the required signal is 0.5 microvolt lsb. Till today my preamp was opto-isolated but connected to PC based system. It has CM and capacitive induction troubles. I wish to improve it to bluetooth or IR-opto isolated. So it will be good improvement.

Comment: I made an actual experiment so as to get better idea. I hooked up a small circuit, made the mains wiring arrangement with 0.3 amp current and found that it induces about 1 microvolt in same length wire at distance of 50 mm. Of coarse, I am still looking for proper formula.... Thanks.